# moving pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a 2-dimensional array defined like:

```
size = 100;
int i,j;
a = new double *[size+1];

for (i=0;i<=(size);i++)  {
    a[i] = new double [size+1];
}
for (i=0;i<=size;i++) {
     for (j=0;j<size+1;j++) {

         a[i][j] = (double) 0;
     }
}
```

Now when I try to access e.g. a[1][150] I get out-of-bound error which is reasonable. However, after adding the following section, a[1][150] is accessible and initialized.

```
for (i=1;i<=size;++i) {
    a[i]-=i;
}
```

It seems the dimension of array a, is changed to 100*200. In general a[i][j] is initialized where `0<i<101 and 0<j<201`. How is that possible?

Comment: An aside: C++ is zero based, indexing from `1` to `<=size` will index out of bounds.

Comment: There is just so much wrong here I don't have enough years left in my life to get into it right now. However, I have provided a _direct_ answer to your immediate question.

Comment: Why cast 0 to a double? If you want a double, write 0.0.
And your code just reiterates over the array, it doesn't even try to go farther than the current size: why did you expect it to resize the array?

Comment: @CoryKramer size of the array is (size+1). But the size of the array is 101*101

Comment: @KABoissonneault I think this behaviour is because of moving pointers after initialization and the not deleting the old ones. I'm sure after running the second part you can put values greater than size in the column index and get 0 or whatever initialized value used .

Comment: After `a[i] -= i`, your valid indexes are `0<i<101 and i<j<i+100`, NOT `0<j<201`

Answer (score 3):

Noise aside, what you're doing is essentially this :

```
// Allocate an array of 10 doubles
// and store the address of the first one in a
double *a = new double[10];

// Access the sixth double
a[5] = 1.7;

// Shift a by 100 times the size of a double
a -= 100;

// Access the sixth double, again.
assert(a[105] == 1.7);
```

`a` is just a pointer, and does not hold any information about the array it points to. There's no bounds checking either : `a[n]` is strictly equivalent to `*(a + n)`. So once `a` has been moved 100 slots backwards, the array's space appears to have moved 100 slots forwards, relative to `a`.

That's what happens on your machine, but not what the standard mandates. Only pointers that point at, inside, or right after an object are valid. Using any other pointer  is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! But in the code I asked about all the memory locations after the pointer location are initialized after moving! This is further than just moving the pointer to another place and using the offset.

Comment: @ahb65 here's an hypothesis : gdb is smart enough to detect that `a[x]` points at an array, and preemptively stops you from accessing it out-of-bounds. Once you shifted every `a[x]`, even by a single unit, gdb loses track and trusts you instead, accessing whatever you requested. Having made all your dynamic allocations at once, there's good chance that the subarrays have been laid out sequencially in the heap, which is why you stumble upon one of them by accessing past the first one.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the case! The array can be treated the same as a n*2n array inside the program!

Comment: @ahb65 if you want any more certainty than "it's undefined behaviour" and "mayyyyyybe it's because...", you'll need to dig down into your kernel to see how heap allocation is done there, and why this madness appears to work. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you answers were really helpful. I don't know why people hate this question so much. That's what I ran into while coding and my claim can be tested easily.

Comment: @ahb65 the thing to never, ever do in C and C++ is try something weird "to see if it works" without documenting oneself, and quickly conclude that it does if it happens to give the expected result. Questions stemming from this (especially the indexing-out-of-bounds flavour) are legion, and people here are fed up because the answer is always "undefined behaviour, check the documentation first because C won't stop you from shooting your foot off".

Comment: In fact I am reusing another code which is written like this and mathematically it should have done on an n*2n array. Magically, it works correctly due to this behaviour.